# How do you modify a user on CentOS to access the root directory or any directory outside of home via vsftpd

Tags: centos, ftp

How do you modify a user on CentOS to access the root directory or any directory outside of home via vsftpd?

Comment: Are you asking if you can allow a user to ftp into a server and gain access to directories other than the one specified by your vxftpd configuration?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found an easy way to do this with out affecting security.

Created a directory under the user home folder and bind it to the root directory.

Thanks all anyway!

Comment: can you tell exactly how you achieved this?

Comment: mount --bind folder folder

Answer (score -2):

With CentOS you have three things to keep in mind 
1. the VSFTPD config file
2. the permissions on the directories that you set
3. SELinux

if you have SELinux disabled this becomes easier if not you will have to write a policy to allow this access.  Changing the config file and the permissions should be fairly straight forward.

Comment: The web is awash with suggestions to disable SELinux, even passive ones.

Comment: He is asking to access the root directory of a server with a FTP server ... from his question I assumed security wasn't his first priority

Comment: Following http://linux.die.net/man/8/ftpd_selinux will be better than disabling selinux, not that this is that good of an idea anyway!